# How to whitelist special characters in ORACLE APEX

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle-apex, apex

I just want to know how to maximize the use of regexp_like for whitelisting special characters. And it results as invalid when the declared value is $

**Whitelist**

- Characters - $“-/?!%.,:;’()
- Alphabets and numbers - A-Z, a-z, 0-9

**Here's my code below**

```
declare
  l_value varchar2(32767) := '$';
begin
  if regexp_like(l_value,'[a-zA-Z0-9]$“-/\?!%.,:;’()') then
    dbms_output.put_line('valid');
  else
      dbms_output.put_line('invalid');  
  end if;
end;
```

Thanks everyone.

Comment: can you provide an example of what is happening and where ? is in APEX or in SQLPLUS ?

Comment: Please don't post duplicate question. This is the same question that you posted 5 hours ago but with more detail. Instead update the existing question next time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of things wrong with your code:

- All the characters should be between the square brackets, the square brackets indicate the list of characters to whitelist
- as soon as there is a single characters in the `l_value` that is in the class it will render valid. To avoid that check for all characters between the start `^` and end `$`

```
DECLARE
  l_value varchar2(32767) := '$';
BEGIN
  IF REGEXP_LIKE(l_value,'^[a-zA-Z0-9$"/\?!%.,:;’()-]*$') THEN
    dbms_output.put_line('valid');
  ELSE
    dbms_output.put_line('invalid');  
  END IF;
END;
/
```

It's easier to test this with a set of sample data in a select - like this:

```
WITH sampledata (v) AS
(
  SELECT '$' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT '$foo' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT '+' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT '_' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'f_oo' FROM dual 
)
SELECT * FROM sampledata
 WHERE REGEXP_LIKE(v,'^[a-zA-Z0-9$"/\?!%.,:;’()-]*$');
```

Comment: What does * represent before $ in here?

```IF REGEXP_LIKE(l_value,'^[a-zA-Z0-9$"-/\?!%.,:;’()]*$') THEN```

Comment: Check the docs: https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/adfns/regexp.html#GUID-1935FD80-A3CD-413F-BD2E-BBEFE64000B2 . A "*" is "zero or more of the preceding subexpression"

Comment: If I tried to input the plus sign (+) in l_value it says valid but it's not whitelisted on the set of special characters that was set. Could anyone explain please? Thank you.

Comment: Updated my answer. A lot of testing and reading docs *(you should !)* learned me that *A dash (-) is a literal when it occurs first or last in the list,*. So you need the "-" at the end of the list.

Comment: Another question, how do we add new line in a set of regexp? I tried to insert at the end of the list but doesn't work too. '^[a-zA-Z0-9$"/\?!%.,:;’()-\n]*$'

Comment: Please don't ask followup questions in the comments. Only the persons that have replied will see your comment - this is a question that other community members can reply to as well. Post a new question instead with some example code to illustrate what you're trying to achieve

Comment: Thanks for reminding. Already asked another question for this concern. @Koen Lostrie